# Как инициализируется файл py?

Tags: python

У меня есть исполнительный файл к примеру `main.py` и обычный файл `file.py`. В `Java` что-бы вызвать `file.py` мне бы пришлось создать новый класс в нем же(`file.py -> class file`) и создать его экземпляр в `main.py` что-бы обратиться к функциям и объектам `file.py`. Вопрос в том что я не понимаю когда инициализацируется `file.py` в `main.py`, тогда когда я импортирую его `from file.py import obj`  или когда вызываю `obj.get_func()`.

Внутри `file.py` происходит инициализация некоторых объектов. И из-за этого мне кажется что каждый раз при вызове `obj.get_func()` я создаю новый экземпляр файла, верно?

```
from file import obj

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
          obj.get_func()
```

Comment: Нет, все происходит при импорте

Comment: что такое `obj` , покажите что у вас в `file.py`

Comment: @S.Nick у меня есть два файла в первом исполняется Flask во втором инициализация бота. obj есть сам бот который при app.route(/bot/) принимает сообщение от бота. Проблема заключается в том что бот через каждых 7-8 часов перестает отвечать, все запросы по Flask проходят на ура. в логах чисто. Думал что проблема в том что создал несколько экземпляров бота

Comment: попробуйте перед `while` создать объект `_obj = obj()`, а в цикле `_obj.get_func()`